# ReactNatice app (Android) do not receive the notification from Firebase Cloud Message

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making a process for receiving notifications from Firebase Cloud Message. And I followed the instruction, [Installation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup). And I write code like below.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const IS_DEBUGGIN_MODE = true;
const styles = {
  constainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  },
};

function log(message, ...args) {
  if (IS_DEBUGGIN_MODE) {
    console.log(message, ...args);
  }
}

class AppSettingComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.removeNotificationListener;
    this.removeNotificationOpenedListener;
    this.removeMessageListener;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._checkPermission();
    this._listenForNotifications();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeNotificationListener();
    this.removeNotificationOpenedListener();
    this.removeMessageListener();
  }
  async _checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    log('###### _checkPermission : ', enabled);
    if (enabled) {
      log('###### _updateTokenToServer');
      this._updateTokenToServer();
    } else {
      log('###### _requestPermission');
      this._requestPermission();
    }
  }
  async _requestPermission() {
    try {
      await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      await this._updateTokenToServer();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('The Error is occurred in AppSettingComponent _requestPermission : ', [err]);
    }
  }
  async _updateTokenToServer() {
    const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    log('_updateTokenToServer : ', fcmToken);
  }
  async _listenForNotifications() {
    // onNotificationDisplayed - IOS only

    log('###### get in _listenForNotifications');

    this.removeNotificationListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotification(notification => {
        log('###### onNotification', notification);
      });

    this.removeNotificationOpenedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
        log('###### onNotificationOpened', notificationOpen);
      });

    this.removeMessageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage(message => {
      log('###### onMessage : ', message);
    });

    const notificationOpen = await firebase
      .notifications()
      .getInitialNotification();

    if (notificationOpen) {
      log('###### getInitialNotification open : ', notificationOpen);
    } else {
      log('###### getInitialNotification close : ', notificationOpen);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <View style={styles.container} />;
  }
}

export default AppSettingComponent;
```

And when I send the Cloud Message using Firebase, there is nothing happened in debugger console. The following is the console after open the app.

```
###### get in _listenForNotifications
###### _checkPermission :  true
###### _updateTokenToServer
###### getInitialNotification close :  null
_updateTokenToServer : 'my device token(FCM token)'

// no more console, even after I send a notification message.
```

Is there anything I miss? How can I receive the notification message?

addition :
When I'm setting the notification message and then setting **2. Target**, there is an app which I registered and I selet it for target. **But** below the targeting of app, there is message like `The 0% of potential users satisfy the conditions of this campaign` (I'm Korean, and I translate the message to English, i.e, the exact message can be different).
Is it problem to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was the **integrating Firebase to Android** process. (Firebase project couldn't integrate my app)

The problem of it was the `updating of Gradle` (the version of Gradle was 3.x). So, I resolve this issue with following process.

1. After setting of android `build.gradle` etc(my `react-native-firebase` version is `^5.6.0` and I follow the instruction of [Android Installation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android)), I open the android project of react-native with **Android Studio**.
2. Then the Android Studio start build.
3. In progress of building the project, Android Studio suggest the update Gradle to version `5.x`.

After Update the Gradle version, Firebase can integrate my app and push notification work.